# missing zlib.dll

Tags: windows, dll, dynamic, linker

I am building a win32 executable. The compiler is the latest version of MinGW. The library dependencies are GLUT and libpng.

I first tested on a windows 7 machine, and had to obtain libpng3.dll and freeglut32.dll. However, on XP, I had to (in addition) acquire zlib1.dll.

The XP machine was a VM with a fresh install, so I suspect a fresh win7 machine may also be lacking zlib1.

My question is how do I go about finding out which dll's I need to distribute? How do I know, *a priori*, which dynamic libraries are needed for my program to run on a particular system? I suppose this is what installer programs are for... I'm guessing that what the installer does is look through the system to find out which dependencies are unsatisfied, and then provides them. So this way if I were to distribute my program I could check if the user's machine already has zlib1.dll, and I won't install zlib1.dll if it's already found in the system directory. However I never found a document that said to me specifically, "libpng requires zlib", and so, until such point as I tested the executable on a machine lacking zlib, I was unaware of this dependency. How can I create my dependency list without having a fresh install of each version of every operating system to test on?

One idea I have is to decompile the executable, or through some method examine the linking process, to find all the libraries that are being linked at runtime. The problem now becomes figuring out which of these are supposed to already be there, and which of them I could be expected to provide in the distribution.

**edit:** Okay, I looked, and the installation of libpng I downloaded did provide zlib1.dll inside its bin directory. So not including it is pretty much my fault. In any case, Daniel's answer is definitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dependendy Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) shows all deps of your program.

Comment: Nearly every question involving DLLs has one answer referring to this tool :))

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer to this question, in my view, is to start at the source rather than to reverse engineer the solution with Dependency Walker, awesome and useful tool though it undoubtedly is.

The problem with Dependency Walker is that it only tells you what one particular run of the program requires on the OS on which you run it. If you have any dynamic loading dependencies in your app then you would only pick those up if you made sure you profiled the app with Dep. Walker and forced it through those dynamic loads.

My preferred approach to this problem is to start with your own source code and analyse and understand what it depends upon. It's often easy enough to do so because you know it well.

You need to understand what are the deployment requirements for your compiler. You usually have options of linking statically and dynamically to the C++ runtime. Obviously a dynamic link results in a deployment requirement.

You will also likely link to 3rd party code. One example would be Windows components. These typically don't need deployment, you can take them as already being in place. Sometimes that's not true, e.g. GDI+ on Windows 2000.

Sometimes you will link statically to 3rd party code (again easy), but if you link dynamically then that implies a deployment requirement.

Comment: yeah, this makes sense, thanks. My original motivation was laziness -- I just wanted an easy way out. But i guess i just need to bite the bullet.

Comment: @Steven Dependency Walker is a great tool and very useful for diagnosing issues in a top-down manner. But you will also benefit from understanding your dependencies from the bottom-up too.